# Maximum a Poseriori Derivation

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability

can anyone please tell me how the author came to equation 2 from equation 1. I've applied Bayes rules but I'm not able to come to equation 2 directly. Thanks so much in advance.

[image: MAP derivation]

Answer (score 0):

These two are equal by definition of Bayes theorem :)

[image]